# Find out to which highlight-group a particular keyword/symbol belongs in vim

Tags: vim, themes, textmate

I am coming to Vim from TextMate, and I would like to customise my vim colorscheme. It would be really helpful if I could find out to which highlight-group(s) any particular word or symbol belongs. In TextMate, I would place the caret on the word/symbol in question, then hit ctrl-shift-p and a tool tip would appear saying something like:

```
text.html.basic
meta.tag.structure.any.html
string.quoted.double.html
```

From this information, it is really straightforward to edit a TextMate color theme to apply (or remove) formatting to the text in question.

In Vim, if I want to change formatting for a certain word or symbol, I'm not sure where to start. Is there anything equivalent to TextMate's ctrl-shift-p?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood right, but are you looking for this ?

```
" adds to statusline
set laststatus=2
set statusline+=%{synIDattr(synID(line('.'),col('.'),1),'name')}

" a little more informative version of the above
nmap <Leader>sI :call <SID>SynStack()<CR>

function! <SID>SynStack()
    if !exists("*synstack")
        return
    endif
    echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

Comment: I just made one change: mapping the command to ctrl-shift-p for the sake of consistency. `nmap <C-S-P> :call <SID>SynStack()<CR>`

Answer (score 20):

Another way to get lots of information about the highlighting:

```
map <F3> :echo "hi<" . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name") . '> trans<' . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),0),"name") . "> lo<" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"name") . ">" . " FG:" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"fg#")<CR>
```

If I move over a comment in a C file and press <kbd>F3</kbd>, I get:

```
hi<cCommentStart> trans<cCommentStart> lo<Comment> FG:#00ff00
```

which shows that it is in the highlight group `cCommentStart`, which is linked to `Comment` and coloured in green (`#00ff00`).  This is (modified) from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor), see that page for more information.

Comment: This is awesome. I find this much more helpful than the simple `hi` identifier.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: From `:help synID()` (see the example):

```
synID({line}, {col}, {trans})                           *synID()*
                The result is a Number, which is the syntax ID at the position
                {line} and {col} in the current window.
                The syntax ID can be used with |synIDattr()| and
                |synIDtrans()| to obtain syntax information about text.
                {col} is 1 for the leftmost column, {line} is 1 for the first
                line.
                When {trans} is non-zero, transparent items are reduced to the
                item that they reveal.  This is useful when wanting to know
                the effective color.  When {trans} is zero, the transparent
                item is returned.  This is useful when wanting to know which
                syntax item is effective (e.g. inside parens).
                Warning: This function can be very slow.  Best speed is
                obtained by going through the file in forward direction.

                Example (echoes the name of the syntax item under the cursor):  
                        :echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

<s>As far as I know, the best you can do is `:syntax`, which will give you a listing of all the syntax loaded for the current file.  I don't know of anything that will give the syntatical parsing of the current buffer.</s>

Note that `:syntax` just defines the syntax items, it's uses of the `:highlight` command that give the coloring for a syntax item.

Once you've decided what changes you want to make, put them in `~/.vim/after/syntax/<filetype>.vim`.  These will apply your changes after the default syntax files are loaded.

Comment: The help docs for Vim are outstanding, but I couldn't have found the information on synID without your help. Thanks.

Also, the tip about overriding syntax files by putting them in the `after` directory is much appreciated.

Comment: @nelstrom - by way of "help vimfiles" you can see which directories have preferences over which (the \after part).

Comment: @nelstrom - a quick way to see what might be a relevant help topic is to use the CTRL-D keystroke to see possible completions when typing `:help syn`  - it'll show you all the help topics that match the string "syn", which is how I found `synID()`.

Comment: How to revert "Once you've decided what changes you want to make, put them in `~/.vim/after/syntax/<filetype>.vim`." ? Please. If I comment that changes, then the highlight is `cleared`, instead of just revert to keep the **original plugin color-scheme**.