# Vim: Get content of syntax element under cursor

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm on a highlighted complex syntax element and would like to get it's content. Can you think of any way to do this?

Maybe there's some way to *search for a regular expression so that it contains the cursor*?

**EDIT**

Okay, example. The cursor is inside a string, and I want to get the text, the content of this syntactic element. Consider the following line:

```
String myString = "Foobar, [CURSOR]cool \"string\""; // And some other "rubbish"
```

I want to write a function that returns

```
"Foobar, cool \"string\""
```

Comment: To simply find the syntax group at a position see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467438/find-out-to-which-highlight-group-a-particular-keyword-symbol-belongs-in-vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Seeing that the plugin mentioned by nelstrom works similar to my original approach, I settled on this slightly more elegant solution:

```
fu s:OnLink()
    let stack = synstack(line("."), col("."))
    return !empty(stack)
endf

normal mc 

normal $
let lineLength = col(".")
normal `c

while col(".") > 1
    normal h
    if !s:OnLink()
        normal l
        break
    endif
endwhile
normal ma`c

while col(".") < lineLength
    normal l
    if !s:OnLink()
        normal h
        break
    endif
endwhile
normal mb`av`by
```

Comment: So your function scans to the left and right of the cursor position, and will stop when the syntax stack is empty. This way, you will however only capture a syntax element that is on one line, and you will have problems with neighbouring elements.

Answer (score 10):

if I understood the question. I found this gem some time ago and don't remember where but i used to understand how syntax hilighting works in vim:

```
" Show syntax highlighting groups for word under cursor
nmap <leader>z :call <SID>SynStack()<CR>
function! <SID>SynStack()
  if !exists("*synstack")
    return
  endif
  echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

Comment: This is a good start, but it only gives me the names of the syntax groups. I need the content.

Comment: Can you please explain how can this be used ?
I don't know much about vim `syntax` highlighting - but it seems like a gem but I don't its significance. :(

Comment: Wonderfull !! `:echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')`

Answer (score 4):

The [textobj-syntax](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2716) plugin might help. It creates a custom text object, so that you can run `viy` to visually select the current syntax highlighted element. The plugin depends on the [textobj-user](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100) plugin, which is a framework for creating custom text objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use for text objects (`:help text-objects`).  To get the content you're looking for (`Foobar, cool \"string\"`), you can just do:

```
yi"

y = yank
i" = the text object "inner quoted string"
```

The yank command by default uses the unnamed register (`""`, see `:help registers`), so you can access the yanked contents programmatically using the `getreg()` function or the shorthand `@{register-name}`:

```
:echo 'String last yanked was:' getreg('"')
:echo 'String last yanked was:' @"
```

Or you can yank the contents into a different register:

```
"qyi"
```

yanks the inner quoted string into the `"q` register, so it doesn't conflict with standard register usage (and can be accessed as the `@q` variable).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not general enough. I didn't know that i" ignores escaped quotes, nice!

Comment: Because of the flexibility in how Vim syntax authors can specify language elements, you might have a hard time finding something that works as a general "inner syntactic element".