# How to change colors of local anchors in headers

Tags: vim, markdown, syntax-highlighting

in my markdown files I have a summary at the top with inner links to the document headers. Something like this:

```
   # my doc
   ## Summary
     * [Introduction](#intro)
     ...
   
   ## <a name="intro"></a>Introduction
   Lorem blahblahblah
```

I have customized the *heading delimiters* to appear with the same color of *comments* using the following statement:

```
   hi def link markdownHeadingDelimiter Comment
```

I would like to customize the entire part represented by the inner anchor `<a name="intro"></a>`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command to see what highlight group is assigned to the text under your cursor:

```
:command! SynStack echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
```

In this case, every single character of `<a name="intro">` belongs to `htmlTag` and every single character of `</a>` belongs to `htmlEndTag` so that's a start. But there are other highlight groups at play, like `htmlString`, and you will have to deal with them individually.

Comment: Hi and thanks. I'm trying to run that command but nothing appears...

Comment: In the end I used a function copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5825964/1362003) and with your suggestion I have been able to fix.
Basically I had to link the following highlight groups: htmlTag, htmlTagName, htmlString, htmlArg and htmlEndTag