# How to figure out which color group a piece of code belongs to in VIM

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to figure out which color-group a piece of code belongs to?
I'm struggling to get my colorscheme to work nicely with various filetypes. It would be handy to have a command that prints out the current color-group for the text at the current cursor position.

for example ([X] marks the cursor position:

```
def foobar
  @some[X]thing = "foo"
end
```

would print out "Identifier" (If I'm right about that one ;-))
Is anything like that possible?
Or do you have any other recommendation how to "solve" the problem of identifying the right color groups to use?

Comment: thanks for pointing this out (dunno why this is worth downvoting though). Voted for close because of duplicate

Comment: I didn't downvote, only closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [Find out to which highlight-group a particular keyword/symbol belongs in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467438/find-out-to-which-highlight-group-a-particular-keyword-symbol-belongs-in-vim)

In addition, there's even a ready-to-use plugin for that: [SyntaxAttr.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383)