# Vim highlighting - is there a way to find out what is applied at a particular point?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to tweak my highlighting. Vim highlighting is pretty complex, as I understand, lots of rules run to determine the category of a bit of text, then those rules are mapped and possibly mapped again through to a final category, which is then mapped to a treatment dependent on the environment (term/cterm/gui)!

As I'm on cterm there are more combinations than colours, so you get duplicates and it's not always obvious which highlighting category ("group"?) has been applied where.

I would like to put my cursor over a highlighted word and run a command to see what highlight rules matched and how that got mapped to a final treatment.

Is that a feature? Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out to which highlight-group a particular keyword/symbol belongs in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467438/find-out-to-which-highlight-group-a-particular-keyword-symbol-belongs-in-vim)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create such mapping:

```
nm <silent> <F1> :echo "hi<" . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")
    \ . '> trans<' . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),0),"name")
    \ . "> lo<" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"name")
    \ . ">"<CR>
```

And use <kbd>F1</kbd> on any token to see the highlighting.

Comment: That's amazing! vimscript is like voodoo to me - no idea! So it outputs `hi` (name of highlighting group), and `trans` and `lo`?

Comment: Yes, doing it on `while` keyword in C displays `hi<cRepeat> trans<cRepeat> lo<Statement>`

Comment: What do trans and lo mean?

Comment: `trans` represents transparent item highlighting, and `lo` is for inherited highlighting. Usually they are the same, but not always. Read more `:h transparent`

Comment: Any reason it doesn't echoes the `Search` highlight group when hlsearch is on? @svlasov

Comment: @Moshe `Search` is a _highlight group_, while `synID*` functions work for _syntax groups_ only, defined with `:syntax` commands. Syntax and highlight groups are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To find out which syntax group causes highlighting, `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. I find this plugin indispensable for troubleshooting and developing syntax plugins! (Basically, it's an advanced version of @svlasov's answer.)